# Split the Quarter data in a table into monthly SQL server

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can you help out with a problem

I have  table  name QuarterIndex where quarterly indexes are available Eg:

```
31 December 2014 - 2.0 %
31 March 2015 - 2.1 %
30 June 2015- 2.33 %
```

I need to write a query which can split these indexes monthly based on the below formula and return it monthly going forward..The data will keep on growing for the future quarters

Here is the formula -- Formula can be modified later.So not much importance should be given to formula.

(=(1+Q1 index)^(1/12)-1)

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Would you add your desire output to your question, also tell us what have you done till now

Comment: Can you provide query which has selected these data? So we can modify it?

Comment: you want to raise it to the 1/12 power (^) or multiply it by 1/12 (which is the same as dividing it by 12)

Comment: Right Beth.The formula is not important.I would just substitute the right one to get the compounding values split across month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
create function quarter_to_month
(
    @from date,
    @to date
) returns table
as return
(
    with [base] as
    (
        select @from [from], dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 1, @from)) [to]
        union all
        select dateadd(month, 1, [from]), dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 2, [from]))
        from [base]
        where dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 2, [from])) <= @to
    )
    select * from [base]
)
go

create table QuarterIndex
(
    [end] date, 
    [percent] float
);
go

insert into QuarterIndex ([end], [percent]) values
('31 December 2014', 2.0),
('31 March 2015', 2.1),
('30 June 2015', 2.33);
go

with QuarterIndex_with_begin_date as
(
    select cast(left(convert(varchar, dateadd(month, -2, [end]), 112), 6) + '01' as date) [begin]
    , [end]
    , [percent] 
    from QuarterIndex
)
select datename(month, x.[from]) [mname], x.[from], x.[to]
, power((1+[percent]), (1/12)-1) [percent] --> you can change the formula if i'm wrong
from QuarterIndex_with_begin_date q
cross apply quarter_to_month ([begin], [end]) x
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Result

```
mname       from        to          percent
-----------------------------------------------------
October     2014-10-01  2014-10-31  0.33333
November    2014-11-01  2014-11-30  0.33333
December    2014-12-01  2014-12-31  0.33333
January     2015-01-01  2015-01-31  0.32258
February    2015-02-01  2015-02-28  0.32258
March       2015-03-01  2015-03-31  0.32258
April       2015-04-01  2015-04-30  0.30030
May         2015-05-01  2015-05-31  0.30030
June        2015-06-01  2015-06-30  0.30030
```

check (old) [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f4beb/1)

check (new) [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf7ae/1)

Comment: Thanks Andrey.I tried your solution unfortunately my table just provides me data without the start date or begin date as suggested in your solution.